# browse website with powershell without using internet explorer

Tags: powershell, web

Is there any possibility to load,navigate and interact with a website in Powershell?
I readed about `New-WebServiceProxy` and `Http-Request`. But they both seem to only be able to download some content and can't interact with the website.

I know that i could use Internet Explorer in Powershell but in my Environment this is not possible. For this reason I am searching for another solution.

Comment: You can't browse a web site without using a browser?! Powershell isn't a browser

Comment: Ok thank you! So I would have to do it otherwise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of 'browsing' websites through Powershell, not in the traditional sense of the word anyway.

However, you can **download and upload content, create web service requests, login to websites, etc.** through the [web-client class](https://nyquist212.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/powershell-webclient-example/) and [invoke-webrequest cmdlet](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_invoke_webrequest.htm).

Again, not in anyway like a graphical browser, but very useful for repetitive tasks that do not require much human intervention

Comment: This one might be more relevant to your needs, the example at the bottom shows how to login to facebook:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx

Comment: Ok that doesnt work for my case, but could be interessting for future scripts. Thanks for your interssting and detailed answer!