# How to configure wordPress?

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu, ssh, server

I am working with SSH in W10 powershell. how can I open localhost/blog in wordPress from browser as described in this link: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#5-configure-wordpress

NOTE: the earlier steps done succesfully with powershell.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if your machine is local, just use your default browser on navigation bar and type **localhost/blog** or **127.0.0.1/blog**. If it's a remote server, from your machine, instead of using **localhost** or **127.0.0.1**, use the remote server IP (something like **http://177.5.5.12/blog**). Or are you trying directly through SSH?

Comment: I think your answer fixed the problem. for general knowledge, how can I connect directly from ssh?

Comment: It's possible you query some information using Net.WebClient Class, like DownloadString from a WebSite, see here please -> https://learn-powershell.net/2011/02/11/using-powershell-to-query-web-site-information/

But actually surfing on websites like a internet browser I don't think it's possible, there's a thread here explaining this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26996001/browse-website-with-powershell-without-using-internet-explorer